# Ignoring ProviderUserKey in Custom Role Provider Implementation

Tags: c#, membership, provider, sqlmembershipprovider

I have no use for the ProviderUserKey in the MembershipUser object, as my roles database has it's own ID's.

If I'm using C#, how do I call the membershipuser constructor so that it creates the user without this key?

What are the implications of not providing this key to the provider? Does the ProviderUserKey become part of the Principal object in the FormsAuthentication cookie?

Answer (score 0):

What unique value do you use to identify a user in your database?  Whatever that value is, store it in ProviderUserKey...

Comment: I'm getting errors when I try to modify the SQLMembershipProvider code as it expects a GUID, not an int...

Comment: Correction: I was able to get it to work as an int; I was doing something wrong in the database...